# Why doesn't jooq allow a Record in whenNotMatchedInsert?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

In a merge query, I can always do:

```
public <R> void insertOrUpdateRecord(TableRecord<R> record, Condition match, Map<? extends Field<?>, ?> updates) {
    ctx.mergeInto(record.getTable()).using(ctx.selectOne())
       .on(match)
       .whenMatchedThenUpdate()
       .set(updates)
       .whenNotMatchedThenInsert(record.fields())
       .values(toArray(record));
}
```

Here `toArray` converts a `TableRecord` -> `Object[]` in the same order as the corresponding fields returned in `record.fields()`.

So, is there any reason why I can't do this directly:

```
whenNotMatchedThenInsert(record)
```

Since, the aim is pretty much to insert a new record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired feature is already available, with a slightly different syntax:

```java
   .whenNotMatchedThenInsert()
   .set(record);
```

This will take into account all the values from the argument record, for which the [`Record.changed(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#changed-org.jooq.Field-) flag is `true`